# Vaadin 23.2.11 unable to package for production

Tags: vaadin23

When trying to package my project like mentioned on the Vaadin 23 website : mvn clean package -Pproduction I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.11:build-frontend (default) on project fi.laji.taxoncontent: Execution default of goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.11:build-frontend failed: Unable to valida
> te the license, please check your internet connection. If you need to work offline then please go to https://vaadin.com/pro/validate-license?getOfflineKey=mid-0aec3256-1dded399 to retrieve an offline key.

I was under the impression that I do not need a license if I am not using paid features (such as, Vaadin Charts) or tools (such as, Vaadin TestBench).

How do I properly deploy my vaadin 23 project for production?
I'm using java 17 and here is my pom.xml production configuration:

```
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a license for using Vaadin free components. But You may need an internet connection to resolve your dependecies.